# Why do I get error "Build: process completed with exit code 5" in my python repo on Github?

Tags: python, build, pytest, github-actions

When I try to run build workflow on github for my new python repo, it fails with "build Process completed with exit code 5."

I tried to re-run the workflows, but the issue still persists. How can I fix it?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: What issue? Post an error message at least.

Comment: i have added an image with the exact error. let me know if you come across something similar

Comment: You have not added the exact error. The exact error is somewhere inside that build phase, please add it as text.

Comment: Actually I believe that is the exact error, that's enough. You don't have tests, that's why it fails. You need to either add them (it can just be a placeholder that asserts true) or configure the behaviour for "no tests passed". See https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/2393

Comment: Though, btw, yes - generally please try to add errors as text, not as an image link. Links can become broken and if that happens your question is of no use to the next person who tries to find an answer. For example, there is no way to arrive from a search like "what does error 5 mean python github" to your question.

Comment: Surprisingly I didn't find a duplicate for this, so I edited the question somewhat and posted this as an answer.. lemme know if there actually is one

Answer (score 1):

In this case code 5 is returned from pytest and means that no tests were run (see [related PR](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/pull/817), [related issue](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/662)). The rationale for returning non-zero for the case where no tests were configured is: it is better for the build to fail if your test setup was accidentally messed up, otherwise you'd just let your code deploy untested without noticing.

If this is a new repo and you expect it to not have test coverage, the issue will be resolved by adding a "dummy" test like this:

```
def test_dummy():
    pass
```